# Ubuntu 22.04 using fingerprint on a Dell Latitude 5480

Tags: gnome, 22.04, dell, fingerprint-reader

I have installed fprintd and libpam-fprintd and changed the setting in pam-auth-update, but in the gnome gui. I can't see the option to use it. Any Ideas for fixing?

Comment: If your device has Goodix Fingerprint Reader, please understand that it has limited support for Ubuntu.